# What is the need/use for enable annotation processing for Lombok?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-plugin, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am new to maven and was looking into using Lombok.
I added the following to my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.24</version>
</dependency>
```

I also added the following class:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    public class User {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String email;
    }
```

Now what is not clear to me is how from this class code is generated. I have tried an example with json to pojo conversion and for that to work I had to add a plugin to the build cycle.
But in this case with Lombok when I clicked on `package` and then checked under `target/classes` I found that the `User.class` has a bunch of code added based on the anotations.
But how exactly was that code added? I googled a bit and it seems that this code generation happens because of enabling annotation processing in the InteliJ preferences but when I checked my IDE that was not set. So how was the code generated?

[image]

Comment: Lombok hooks into the compiler and alters its behavior.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: But how did that happen without that `Enable annotation processing` set?

Comment: Because lombok hooks into the compiler and alters its behavior.  Precisely how, I don't know but the source is available.